# Automate checking user submitted files

Tags: email

Since last few days, I'm facing some problem. It's about response to 100 users. Situation goes like this. On one end there are 100 user, each user has unique ID. User is supposed to submit one file to server/mail. At receivers end, someone has to check whether submitted file is in particular format or not. I want to automate to this process, starting from server/mailbox where some script should download submitted file, check it and store result in some output file. Can we setup some server on unix machine?can we use some mailbox to which people can send files in the form of an email?

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, there are plenty of options like:

- Setup [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) to run arbitrary scripts/commands received on your inbox, needs server support though
- Use something like [lamson](http://lamsonproject.org/) to create a python application managing emails, you need to forward emails to your lamson server though
- Create filters directly within your Mailserver to filter and control your messages
- Create new [`sieve plugin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_%28mail_filtering_language%29) for filtering your mails.
- Create a program regularly accessing the mailbox via IMAP/pop3/mbox… working with the received emails

Comment: Can't I use sieve within Dovecot to download attachments to local hard disk?

Comment: @user997704 sieve is run on the server side so no you can't use it to download files to your local hard disk. sieve filters typically also don't allow you to run commands so you would have to write your own plugin

Comment: So what should I use to download attachments to local hard disk? I prefer to use Dovecot?

Comment: @user997704 why do you need to download it to your local hard disk? you said you want to run the process on the server but anyway you can use something like offlineimap to synchronize your messages to an Maildir and run your code on it

Comment: I can run process on server but at the same time I want all the attachments to be safe somewhere on my system. Initially my plan was to run process on server to just download attachments and run some other script to process all attachments...all attachments that server process has downloaded will be in specific format...